# Dojo form.FilteringSelect store doesn't get filled immediately

Tags: dojo

I dynamically create a dojo.form.FilteringSelect component like this:

```
new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
        id: 'form_resSelect',
        name: 'resSelect',
        store: store,
        style: {width: '250px'}
    }, resourceContainer );
```

I have noticed that the store gets filled only after clicking on the widget on the rendered form. Are there any properties that can fix this to be immediate or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the store is an `ItemFileReadStore`, you can call the `_forceLoad` function on the store.

```
var store = ...
store._forceLoad();

new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
    id: 'form_resSelect',
    name: 'resSelect',
    store: store,
    style: {width: '250px'}
}, resourceContainer );
```